# how to output a span into a li with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a ul that contain 2 li each of them have a text and a span that contain text like this

```
<ul>
   <li>Erbil<span>text-1</span></li>
   <li>Sulymany<span>text-2</span></li>
</ul>
```

i want to remove **Erbil** and **Sulymany** from the code with jquery.... I'm used this in jQuery

```
$('li').each(function () {
    $('li').html($('span'));
});
```

but the result like this..

```
text-1text-2text-1text-2
text-1text-2text-1text-2
```

how to output only a span without repeating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) and its receiver function to accomplish your task,

```
$('ul li').html(function(){
  return $(this).find('span');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qtC4j/)

Comment: @PshtiwanKarDo Glad to help.. And try to accept any one of the answers here by clicking on the tick mark present with it, And you can shortlist one answer from all the others by thinking how much that helped you in solving your problem.. And purely it is not a compulsion.. :)

Answer (score 1):

At its simplest, assuming it's always the first child you want to remove:

```
$('li').each(function(){
    this.removeChild(this.firstChild);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qtC4j/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? Very crude way though.

```
$('li').each(function () {
    var text = $(this).find('span').html();
    $(this).html('<span>'+text+'</span>');    
});
```